# How can Spring AspectJ weaving work without the -javaagent vm option?

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-aop, javaagents, load-time-weaving

I understand Spring avoids using the `-javaagent` vm option in order to get its AspectJ load time weaving to work and relies instead on a classloader to start the agent.

I thought that the Java specification dictated that the only way to use a Java agent was through the `-javaagent` vm option.

Am I wrong? Can someone please direct me to the official Java specification/documentation that would clarify my interrogation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found some information about loading java agents [in this interesting blog post](http://blog.javabenchmark.org/2013/05/java-instrumentation-tutorial.html).

> Instrumentation Agent To enable JVM instrumentation,  you have to
>   provide an agent (or more) that is deployed as a JAR file. An
>   attribute in the JAR file manifest specifies the agent class which
>   will be loaded to start the agent.
>
> There is 2 ways to load the agent:
>
> - with a command-line interface: by adding this option to the command-line: -javaagent:jarpath[=options] where jarpath is the path
>     to the agent JAR file. options is the agent options. This switch may
>     be used multiple times on the same command-line, thus creating
>     multiple agents. More than one agent may use the same jarpath.
> - by dynamic loading: the JVM must implement a mechanism to start agents sometime after the the VM has started. That way, a tool can
>     "attach" an agent to a running JVM (for instance profilers or ByteMan)
>
> After the JVM has initialized, the agent class will be loaded by the
>   system class loader. If the class loader fails to load the agent, the
>   JVM will abort.
>   ...

Yes official documentation/specification would be more than welcome...

**Edit 1**: At last I came across some relevant and official documentation: API Javadoc for dynamically loading an agent as described in second bullet point above: see [here for VirtualMachine class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html) and [here for loadAgent method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html#loadAgent-java.lang.String-).

**Edit 2**: Also see [this other blog post](http://dhruba.name/2010/02/07/creation-dynamic-loading-and-instrumentation-with-javaagents/). It explains clearly the difference between **static loading of a javaagent at startup** and **dynamic loading of a javaagent at runtime**.

Answer (score 1):

Here a library that initializes aspectj and spring-aspects at runtime by injecting instrumentation: https://github.com/subes/invesdwin-instrument

So no more need for explicit -javaagent argument.

Comment: Awesome tool. But I've been stuck for at least 12 hours now since the site hosting the dependency is down