# Apache Tomcat 8 spring load time weaving is not working for beans loaded by ContextLoaderListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

The issue happened while migrating from tomcat 7 java 7 to tomcat 8 java 8.

In Tomcat 7 load time weaving was working based on loader class specified in the context.xml file

```
<Loader loaderClass="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader"/>
```

As part of migration we removed the above loader class definition from the context.xml and deployed the application to tomcat8.

Now load time weaving is only working for beans loaded by dispatcher servlet
and the **beans in applicationContext.xml  loaded by ContextLoaderListener is not working**? Please provide any suggestions.

*Repeating the same question once more..*

How to prevent the beans in applicationContext.xml **loading before starting load time weaving** ?

Am trying to configure the load time weaver without -javaagent options **is it possible** ?

**Please note the important part of configurations given below**

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    <context:spring-configured />
    <context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="autodetect"/>     
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" mode="aspectj"/>

    <bean id="mainContextLoadingService"
          class="com.riyaskt.trial.service.impl.MainContextLoadingServiceImpl" />
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.riyaskt.trial" />  
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
<bean id="sampleService"
          class="com.riyaskt.trial.service.impl.SampleServiceImpl"          
          p:dao-ref="sampleDao"/>
```

In these two service beans (ie **mainContextLoadingService** in applicationContext.xml and  **sampleService** from **dispatcher servlet**) .

sampleService is weaved properly

but

mainContextLoadingService **is not weaved** by load time weaver..

Comment: Turn on debug logging for org.springframework and check if you are getting any errors for removing the tomcat loader. If yes, edit your main post and add it there.

Answer (score 0):

Try Spring Instrument Jar. Download latest 4.2.3 jar from this [link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-instrument/4.2.3.RELEASE). 
The open launch configuration of your tomcat in eclipse (Double click on your tomcat in **Servers** tab & click on **Open launch configuration**). Now click on **Arguments** tab and append following line to **VM arguments**.

```
-javaagent:<Path to Spring Instrument jar you downloaded>
```

For e.g. you downloaded spring-instrument-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar and placed in D drive, then javaagent argument will be as follow:

```
-javaagent:D:\spring-instrument-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
```

Comment: Am trying to configure the load time weaver without -javaagent option.

Comment: How can can how configure load time weaver per class loader ? not for entire jvm.

Comment: Currently weaving is working without -javaagent  to dispatcher servlet loaded bens

Comment: I am trying for a solution without -javaagent.

Comment: I tried using the -javaagent also but now the dispatcher servlet loaded beans are unable get reference of application context loaded beans.

Comment: We can configure the load time weaver without java agent, ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22580352/how-can-spring-aspectj-weaving-work-without-the-javaagent-vm-option

Comment: @RiyasAbdulla - I am not sure what is wrong with the configuration. I have configured the Spring project with Java Annotation based configuration in which I used `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` ehich is working correctly. If you want to try you can download project from https://github.com/gharia/spring-eclipselink-javaconfig. But in this also I used -javaagent with tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

With  aspectj-weaving="autodetect" attribute, AspectJ weaving will be activated by default if a "META-INF/aop.xml" resource is present on the classpath.